# Amazon SNS Console Push notification sending Empty notification

Tags: android, json, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I want to send push notification via `GCM` to an android phone endpoint. `SNS` is configured and is ready to send notification.In the SNS console using JSON I sent

> { "GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"title\": \"Title\", \"body\":
>   \"Body\" }, \"data\":{} }" }

But I receive only empty notification.No body,no title(only with app icon).

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"test message\" } }"
}
```